# Difficulty parsing comments that come after ; in a line

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm parsing a file that has definitions of functions. Since functions may be written in multiple lines, I'm parsing until encountering a `;`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void removeLineBreaks(std::string &str)
{
    auto pos = str.find('\n');
    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, 1, "");
        pos = str.find('\n', pos);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifStream("a.pr");
    std::string sLine;
    const char sDelim(';');

    while (std::getline(ifStream, sLine, sDelim))
    {
        sLine += sDelim;
        removeLineBreaks(sLine);
        // process further
    }
}
```

The text can be something like this:

```
a=f(b,c); // comment
d=f(e,f);
```

Since I'm reading until `;`, here I get two pieces:

`a=f(b,c);` and

`// comment
\n d=f(e,f);`.

If I call `removeLineBreaks` on the second piece, it'll become `// comment d=f(e,f);` so it'd be treated a comment by my parser.

What options do I have to make this work correctly? I could think of this - before calling `removeLineBreaks` on the line, get the string until `\n`, and if it starts with `//`, cut that part from the line, and only then call `removeLineBreaks`.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Read in the full line and then work backwards until you hit a `;`.

Comment: One way or another you're going to have to remove the comments. Consider the case you haven't encountered yet with the good ol' `/* I_m_not_a_statement; */` comments. You could make a pass through the file find the comments and remove them before you start parsing or you can make a state machine. that goes into a comment state and ignores what it finds until it finds the end of the comment, then returns to the normal processing.

Comment: To do this guaranteed correctly, you really need a full C++ parser.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It does not look to me like OP is trying to parse C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to remove the `//`comments from your input and only then you can split at the semicolons.

Consider the following input:

```
a=f(b,c); // Functions comments are not functions; a=F(b,c);
```

If you first split on semicolons and then remove the comments, then you would end up with two functions:

```
a=f(b,c);
a=F(b,c);
```

But you only want to have the first one.

The solution is to:

1. Read the file line by line (lines delimited by LF).
2. While doing that remove the line based `//` comments and also all line breaks.
3. Combine all input back into a single string.
4. Split the string on semicolons to extract all functions which are outside comments.

The steps do not have to be done sequentially. You can do all these steps simultaneously on the input stream of characters, end emit a stream of functions. In fact, this is what real parsers would do.

You are essentially writing a simple parser. As your language gets more and more complicated you will find it more and more difficult to parse a file in such a way.  For example with the approach above it will be difficult to emit error messages with line number information.

If you want to write a proper parser I would recommend a *recursive descent* parser together with a PEG (parser expression grammar). This approach is easy to learn, has less pitfalls than other approaches and is yet very powerful for computer languages. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar

Warning: If you hear people suggesting `flex` and `bison` (or lex and yacc), I strongly recommend against using them. They are complicated to use and are very limited in what they can parse and how it needs to be specified. I would rather suggest to use a light-weight and modern parsing framework like PEGTL: https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL.

Comment: The problem is that the file is really big, and I can't really save the whole data in the file in memory at once.

Comment: You can do all these steps simultaneously. You do not have to read the file into memory at once.

Comment: @Const Presumably him saying things like "This is half-baked trash software which was never really usable for anything serious.". I'm not a great fan of yacc or bison, but to say they have not been used to write serious software is completely wrong.